# Cumulative count between two specific events in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, running-count

I want to count all steps of each user after 'Start' event in Pandas.

My dataset:

| ID | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Start |
| 1 | Event1 |
| 1 | Start |
| 1 | Event1 |
| 1 | Event2 |
| 1 | Start |
| 2 | Start |
| 2 | Event1 |
| 2 | Start |

I want:

| ID | Event | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Start | 1 |
| 1 | Event1 | 2 |
| 1 | Start | 1 |
| 1 | Event1 | 2 |
| 1 | Event2 | 3 |
| 1 | Start | 1 |
| 2 | Start | 1 |
| 2 | Event1 | 2 |
| 2 | Start | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby`+`cumsum` and then `cumcount`:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(df['Event'].eq('Start').cumsum()).cumcount().add(1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID   Event  Count
0   1   Start      1
1   1  Event1      2
2   1   Start      1
3   1  Event1      2
4   1  Event2      3
5   1   Start      1
6   2   Start      1
7   2  Event1      2
8   2   Start      1
```